# How to Secure PHP code in htm Pages and Partials?

Tags: php, html, laravel, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](http://octobercms.com/), based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), with [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) and [PHP7.0-FPM](https://php-fpm.org/).

I make a Page or Partial using the CMS Backend Editor. Can edit the HTML Markup and Code.

[image: editor]

The Page will render as **localhost/mypage** and hides the php source code.

But I'm able to go to **localhost/themes/mysite/pages/mypage.htm** in the browser and view the Twig markup and PHP comments in plain text.

And on some pages I can view all of the PHP and Laravel code like connection to database names and tables.

Anything that is in function onStart() in the Code editor, even though its wrapped in php tags in the htm file.

**mypage.htm output:**

[image: php plaintext]

However when viewing a .php file, it only shows the output and not the source.

I tried to change the page file extension to php instead of htm but get the error.

```
Invalid file extension: php. Allowed extensions are: htm.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you setup nginx correctly to blacklist those and other unpermitted files? http://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#nginx-configuration

Alternatively, you can take a whitelist approach to security and utilize the `october:mirror` command: http://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#public-folder

Comment: You've pointed me in the right direction. My site is root is /var/www/mysite/public/. I added the rules to sites-available location / {} and outisde the location. Reload and Restarted Nginx. But the htm file still shows.

Comment: I got it to work by using rewrite ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm /index.php break; and putting a slash after ^. So ^/themes/.